# Unable to use timedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I have this code

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.timedelta(base=-1)
```

but Python told me : `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'`

Comment: `datetime.datetime` is a class, as is `datetime.timedelta`

Comment: `base` is also not a valid argument to [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Answer (score 4):

timedelta is part of datetime, and not datetime.datetime, so simply use the following instead:

```
import datetime
start = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

That should do it.

Comment: Base is not a thing

Answer (score 3):

You are essentially trying to access datetime.datetime.datetime

Correct way would be

```
import datetime
start = datetime.timedelta(base=-1)
```

I am not sure if base is a parameter to timedelta,

```
class datetime.timedelta
A duration expressing the difference between two date, time, or datetime instances to microsecond resolution.
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Answer (score 2):

Just use this to directly read in the timedelta function:

```
from datetime import timedelta
start = timedelta(hours=1) #Note base is not a thing
```

Comment: Base is not a thing

Comment: Thanks for the info, it was in reference to the OP.